# shell scripting using sed

Tags: shell

I want to read from standard input, delete all '/', and write the output to standard output. So, a file that contain:

```
/ab1/1a6/ 17
/a/b/1
```

will have output:

```
ab11a6 17
ab1
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
read input
sed -r 's/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/.*/"I not sure what do I need to put in here"/g'
echo $input
```

I don't really know what do I need to put the the "replace" section. any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's./..g'
```

This will delete all `/` characters on each line, so you don't need a replace section.  You can either use the `/` as the delimiter and escape it in the text: `s/\///g` or choose a different punctuation symbol as a delimiter: `s./..g`

So if you want to transform a file called `input.txt` and write the output to `output.txt`:

```
sed 's./..g' input.txt > output.txt
# or
sed 's./..g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest program to do what you've asked is:

```
 tr -d '/'
```

If you enter that you will get what you wanted for output - no / characters  You do not need a `read` or `echo` statement

sed will behave the same as others have shown, tr & sed read from stdin and write to stdout by default:

```
sed 's/\///g'
```

Comment: OP asked specifically for `sed`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing... as shown below:

```
% echo "/ab1/1a6/ 17" | sed 's/\///g'
ab11a6 17
```